# Search for a Value only in one column w.o using awk, sed, or perl

Tags: sed, awk, grep, search, columns

I have a file that looks like this :

```
Marketing  Ranjit Singh   FULLEagles       Dean Johnson   
Marketing  Ken Whillans   FULLEagles       Karen Thompson 
Sales      Peter RobertsonPARTGolden TigersRich Gardener  
President  Sandeep Jain   CONTWimps        Ken Whillans   
Operations John Thompson  PARTHawks        Cher           
Operations Cher           CONTVegans       Karen Patel    
Sales      John Jacobs    FULLHawks        Davinder Singh 
Finance    Dean Johnson   FULLVegans       Sandeep Jain   
EngineeringKaren Thompson PARTVegans       John Thompson  
IT         Rich Gardener  FULLGolden TigersPeter Robertson
IT         Karen Patel    FULLWimps        Ranjit Singh
```

I want to use a grep command to search for "John" in the 2nd column w.o searching the last column, but for every "John" in the 2nd column, I want the output of the last column.

The end result should look like this :

```
       John Thompson                   Cher           
       John Jacobs                     Davinder Singh 
       Dean Johnson                    Sandeep Jain
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to use `grep` for that instead of `awk`. And I doubt that `grep` alone is capable of that.

Comment: i was told that i cannot use awk, sed, or perl. so any solution that excludes them would help.

Answer (score 4):

```
#! /bin/bash
while read line; do
  if [[ ${line:11:15} =~ John ]]; then
    echo "      ${line:11:15}                   ${line:43}"
  fi
done <file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can perform the selection in `grep` by matching the right number of characters from the beginning of the line:

```
grep -E '^.{11,22}John'
```

`John` has to start and end within the range of columns 11–26.

Replacing some columns by whitespace is not within grep's capabilities. With GNU grep, you can use `-o` to output only the matching part, but you won't be able to combine the two columns with additional whitespace in between.

Comment: If it has to end no later than column 25, it can only have 21 characters preceding it, not 26.

Comment: @rici Er, yes, thank you. It's 1–26, actually, so 1,22.

Answer (score 2):

```
tab=$(printf '\t')
cut -c12-26 file | paste - file | grep "^[^$tab]*John" | cut -c1-16,60-
```

Like Gilles said you cannot do it with `grep` alone. `grep` stands for `g/re/p` (a `ed/ex/vi` command), that is, print the lines that match the re.

Answer (score 1):

Let's we combine some hints of the solutions just showed.

From Stephane+ Gilles:

```
grep -E '^.{11,22}John' source.txt  | cut -c12-26,44-
# or, if you want only "John " and not Johnson, add a space after John.
grep -E '^.{11,22}John ' source.txt  | cut -c12-26,44-
```

Here you need to use `/bin/grep` and also `/bin/cut`.

From Gilles + Hauke:

```
grep -E '^.{11,22}John' source.txt | while read line; do echo "${line:11:14} ${line:43}"; done
```

Here you need to use `/bin/grep` and also `echo`.
In modern shell you find `echo` like a *built-in command* so it requires less.

The Hauke's solution is the less expensive in term of installed programs: it requires only `echo` (built-in so `bash`), but not even `/bin/grep`, as wished in the question.

---

**Update** Let's we play a little.
In the everyday life we run *snippet* of code, created on the fly and used maybe nevermore;
not always it results convenient to spend *our human time* to optimize it or to try different variations...
but [*semel in anno licet insanire*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_%28S%29):
on the other hand and with an high probability this was  a `case-study question`, 
maybe even an *homework* not completely clear. In this optic, and IMHO, all the different approaches and solutions are useful.

We all agree, it seems, that for a big number of lines it is better (faster) to use a compiled program
then a sequence of shell commands. But what is big? I think that numbers (and plots) can fix ideas
better than only words: so let's we see.

Here the *recipe*: A set of files with a growing number of lines, ***N***, 
was prepared. Each line was randomly extracted from the 11 original posted here.
The values of *N* used are
    `11 22 55 110 220 550 1100 2200 5500 11000 110000 1100000 11000000`.

The *snippet* tested are:

- The `Cut+Paste+Grep+Cut` `tab=$(printf '\t') ; cut -c12-26 file | paste - file | grep "^[^$tab]*John" | cut -c1-16,60-`  - [Green](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131789/66388)
- The `Only Grep` - Blue [`grep -E '^.{11,22}John' source.txt`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131753/66388). Simply the `grep` with no formatted output as asked.
- The `Grep+Cut`  - Red  [`grep -E '^.{11,22}John' source.txt  | cut -c12-26,44-`].
- The `Grep+While` - Violet [see above in this answer, the grep before and the while loop].
- The `While loop` - Yellow  [a full bash solution that do not require `grep`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131750/66388)

For each size of the files and *snippet*, a number of repetitions, *NRep*,  was made 
starting from 400 (for the shorter files) and decreasing with *N* down to 100, 
10, and 1 for the last one.
It was recorded the value of *Time per line*, ***Tpl***, aka the *real time* as measured by the built-in function 
`time` and averaged on *NRep* and *N*. Since both *Tpl* and *N* span over powers of 10 it was plotted 
the common logarithm (to base 10, or the powers of 10). The lines reported are Bezier curves that touch each point.

[image: Full trend of *Time per Line* vs *Number of lines*]

For large values of *N* the *Time per Line* become almost constant. It is the so-called asymptotic behaviour. 
As expected, the lesser the compiled program used number, the faster the result.

[image: Crossover Region]

On the contrary, with small files, the result is the opposite. 
The efficiencies of different codes cross each other in a region that (for our example) is between 40 and 140 lines.
Even if it is true that for small files is small even the overall *human time* used, 
the same consideration is not anymore valid when it is needed to work with a big number of little files: 
the pure bash code (yellow) that asymptotically is 8.12 times slower than the green one,
and *even 157 times slower* that the red one (for the 11M lines file it uses 334.56 s. instead of 41.21s of the green and 2.16 of the red) 
it is instead respectively 2.16 and 1.58 times faster for the 11 lines one, when it uses 1.20s for 400 repetitions instead of 1.89s of the red or 2.59s of the green.

**Conclusion:** *The more you know, the better you challenge*, and check always when you can! :-)

---

Ps> Similar consideration can be done on the *user time* and *sys time*, but with slightly different crossing region.

*bash*  4.3.11(1)-release
*paste* (GNU coreutils) 8.21
*cut*   (GNU coreutils) 8.21
*grep*  (GNU grep) 2.16
*kernel* 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64

Comment: I would't bet on `bash` to win against `grep` plus reduced `bash` code... Probably less expensive with respect to RAM but probably not faster.

Comment: @HaukeLaging You're right:I had to specify what I mean for _expensive_. :-) I guess this was an homework. So, in this case, less _expensive_ would mean only with less requests _to_ the system, alias less program installed...
for what it concerns speed and memory usage we can check if we remain curios. :-)

Comment: Guys, a shell loop especially in `bash` is always going to be slower than using the right tool for the task (and is bad coding practice) except for very small input. I downvote anything that uses a `while read` loop solely for text processing for no good reason.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas It depends... if you need to deal often with a big number of little files, for example. And what is big or little? More variant you (me, everybody) know, better is. Always IMHO. ;-)

Comment: @HaukeLaging did you know that the only bash  was the faster snippet till 55-56 lines :-) I have no will at all to test memory usage too :)